# Getting Error when publishing in azure synapse or azure data factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am trying to publish the synapse pipelines from master branch.
And I am getting an error and it does not point it to any details or any specific pipeline or Data flow.

Error is below:-

> Error code: OK
> Inner error code: BadRequest
> Message: Missing parameter definition for Env

Comment: Because everything is running fine when I run the pipelines , I d not know why error when publishing. Just to add , Is it possible if I delete the .json files(Deployment and Parameter) from Worskpace_publish branch and then try publishng it again?

Answer (score 1):

> BadRequest Message: Missing parameter definition for Env

is a parameter-passing error that occurs often. Default value can't be expressions. It has to be static value.

You can check if you follow the steps passing parameters:

1. Create parameters in the dataset:

[create parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eJg.jpg)

2. Change the dynamic content to reference the new dataset parameters in the dataset

[change the dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhRIG.jpg)

3. Enter dynamic content referencing the original pipeline parameter in the calling pipeline

[Enter dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKZUT.jpg)

Comment: Hi, 
This is first time I am publishing from master to publish as this is a new project.
I am doing the same thing. Initially I was not setting Default Value. I have also raised this with Microsoft support team, They suggested me to put default value in all the pipelines and DFs as a static value. I already put it. But still getting this error.

Comment: Because everything is running fine when I run the pipelines , I d not know why error when publishing. Just to add , Is it possible if I delete the .json files(Deployment and Parameter) from Worskpace_publish branch and then try publishng it again?